# Is there a crowdsourcing site for code optimization?

Tags: coding-style, optimization

I like clean and well written code, but I don't have the experience or the knowledge (yet) to write code at his best; so, I was wondering if there's a site (like SO) where people can submit snippets, clases, implementations, etc., to be reviewed and posibly improved by other experiencied people, so everybody could learn from their modifications or advices.

I know stack overflow it's pretty much like this, but it is not designed for this purpose I think. Thanks.

Comment: Code review is totally acceptable in SO, as long as it's not too general (i.e. here are 20 classes, please review)

Comment: Yeah, I know, but sometimes users here think its homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://refactormycode.com/ is one.